# Odoo Server Error: Document type: Sales Order Line, Operation: read

Tags: odoo-11

I'm having troubles with an odoo server error.
We use our own installation of odoo 11 community edition and we installed custom modules. One of them is a rental module from webkul.
It has an option to look at rental contracts but with all users except the initial admin account we get the error from the screenshot:

```
Odoo Server Error - Access Error
The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: Sales Order Line, Operation: read) - (Records: [13, 12, 9, 10], User: 64)
```

Even after duplication of the admin account that doesn't get the error, the duplicated accounts gets it.
I checked settings->security->Record Rules but I can not see anything wrong there.
Any ideas on what else I could try out to resolve this issue?
[image: odoo server error]
[image: Record Rules]

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question.
It seems the multi-company setup is not supported by the rental module yet. Having to companies creates the server error because Users are not allowed to look at rental contracts from company A if logged into company B and the other way around.
I copied the Record Rules from Sales Order Line multi-company to the corresponding sales order Line from the rental module record rule and now it works!